# Debug Assertion Failed: Expression vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging, vector

I dont understand why it says subscript out of range when I have reserved the space in the vector. I have created a short form of my code to explain what the problem is better:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    vector<vector<string>> foo;
    thread* aThread;

    A() {
        foo.reserve(10); //makes sure we have space...
        aThread = new thread([this]() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                foo[i].push_back("Hello"); // Debug assertion failed. :(
            }
        });
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.aThread->join();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.foo.size(); j++) {
            cout << a.foo[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here it gives the error as soon as I am trying to add the element into my foo vector inside the thread. I cannot figure out what is wrong. Please help.

Comment: Looks like foo is 2 dimentional array.  you need initialize foo[i] first before push_back.

Comment: I thought the initialization of the whole thing happens from the declaration vector<vector<string>> foo. How do I initialize vectors in the 2d array when I am not sure how many 1d vectors will be stored in it?

Comment: Hi Jerry,  foo[i] should be a vector. It should not push_back a string. It need push_back a vector. Please double check.

Comment: Yes, foo[i] is indeed a vector, and in **that** particular vector I want to push_back a string.

Comment: You reserved space for the 10 vectors of string, but you didn't populate any of them.  Change reserve(10) to resize(10) and it will reserve the space, AND create 10 vectors of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo.reserve(10)
```

Reserves space for elements in foo, but it does not populate any of the elements with an empty std::vector.

You can change it to:

```
foo.resize(10);
```

Which will reserve the space and create the empty vector< string > elements, so that you can access them.